# crowd website simulation on localhost for a php/mysql project

Tags: php, mysql, project, localhost

I searched for a while on how to find a benchmarking software that can simulate crowd website with more than 1000 users online to find out leaks in my php/mysql script .

as long as i ran my script for a huge community and it wasn't successful enough  and lots of RAM usage happened , now  I need a way to simulate that much usage to benchmark my script and optimize it .

I am using XAMMP  Local Server and my project written in PHP&MYSQL.

thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to Google the term "load test" or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at [Apache bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) which allows you to simulate user load of a given web site.

Comment: nice one , but days ago i just used one of these Apache benchmarking script , they are kinda good to be used in crowded websites to benchmark that web server not in localhost for the purpose i mentioned and to make fake or simulated user load on a specific script and the database,